# Filtering search results the Google's way

Tags: userscripts

I'am not fluent in english,so let the images explain it to you

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any userscript or software that can help me achieve this?

I have already tried Google CSE,Chrome personal-blocklist, and they do not work

(Forgot the main point,other users must not notice the tampering)

Comment: Google has so many different pages that it serves, changes rapidly, and uses AJAX and hacks freely.  So doing this, at all, on Google is a whole lot of effort -- if you don't want to be detected -- and a continual maintenance nightmare.  In short, it's a fool's errand.  If this is really for a legit purpose, the solution lies in parenting and people management, NOT attempts to mangle the Google sites.

Comment: Shift+End to highlight to end of line?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I want to exclude torrent sites from search results,that is why "-torrent-download" is added to the textarea.can it be permanently attached to textarea?

Comment: @Brock Adams What about MITM proxy like fiddler or use privoxy or squid+ICAP ?

Comment: Since you are trying to modify what a webpage gets and the content that it returns, that would be even harder.  It's *possible* with a userscript or browser extension -- just not very cost-effective or robust.

Comment: So,where do I start from? any ideas?